# Upgrade php to 7.2 in ubuntu + nginx Vestacp server

Tags: 16.04, nginx

I followed Online tutorial and I installed php 7.2

**php -v** in terminal gives following output

```
PHP 7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2018 04:59:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

But phpinfo() in my website still shows php 7.0 , . I tried restarting

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

, still same .Should I mention somewhere so vestacp use php 7.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `update-alternatives --config php`

(perhaps with sudo)

Idea/Surce :https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/03/27/multiple-php-versions-the-easy-way/